# User/Organization context restriction in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, owasp

I am developing the web service that will serve separate organizations with the same data structure. I am looking for the safer way to keep data of many organizations separated and avoid [insecure direct object references](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References).

I can implement it in the next ways:

1. Pass user id information for each DB query (get the organization of this user, check that requested resource is related to certain organization so on).
2. Create separate database instance for each organization and provide connection string of certain organization during session initialization.

The first way looks a bit boring and requires extra attention to each request. It is easy to miss a validation and some user will be able to explore data from other organizations by passing random id in the own request.

The second way takes off all a headache about extra filtering. But I am going to use cloud database and each new instance requires extra payment so I want to avoid this.

Is it possible to maintain Entity Framework context in another way?

Comment: have the org id as a partition key while storing your records. so you can use it to classify the organizations.

Comment: Depending on the SQL Server version you ae using look into Row Level Security https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx and specifically this example using EF https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-entity-framework-row-level-security/

Comment: @Macilquham you comment is the answer to my question. RLS is solution for my project.

Answer (score 0):

On this question can not be answered unequivocally. You need to consider many factors such as the amount of data in the future, the level of data privacy, whether access to the database is necessary for representatives of organizations,  keep in mind the risk of errors in the design and etc. It is also worth consider the amount of organizations. If a small number of organizations for example up to 3-5 sometimes it makes sense to place the data in a separate databases. Azure allows you to do this without any problems, at least you do not pay for the number of database. If there will  many organizations and your application will have the type of SaaS,  I would have thought, to place data in a single database. Such implementation is not very complicated.